# eXosip2 unknown type name

Tags: c, sip, exosip

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I downloaded:
libosip2-4.0.0.tar.gz
libeXosip2-4.0.0.tar.gz

Untar them and perform a:
./configure
make
make install for each without errors.
When I compile I get this error:

```
gcc -std=c99 qualySip.c
qualySip.c: In function ‘main’:
qualySip.c:32:3: error: unknown type name ‘eXosip_t’
```

This is the code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <eXosip2/eXosip.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 

  // Initialize the osip trace (compile this code with -DENABLE_TRACE)
  int i;
  eXosip_t *ctx;
  int port = 5060;
  TRACE_INITIALIZE (6, NULL);

  // Initialize eXosip (and osip) stack
  ctx = eXosip_malloc();
  if (ctx==NULL)
    return -1;

  i=eXosip_init(ctx);
  if (i!=0)
  return -1;

  // Open a TCP socket for signalling
  i = eXosip_listen_addr(ctx,IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, port, AF_INET, 0);
  if(i != 0){
    eXosip_quit(ctx);
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize transport layer\n");
    return -1;
  }

return 0; //done

}
```

This is the file search:

```
find / -name "eXosip.h"
/usr/include/eXosip2/eXosip.h
/usr/local/src/pcap/libeXosip2-4.0.0/include/eXosip2/eXosip.h
```

I tried as well:

```
gcc -std=c99 qualySip.c -I/usr/local/src/pcap/libeXosip2-4.0.0/include/
```

Answer (score 0):

Put struct before eXosip_t type like:

```
struct eXosip_t *ctx;
```

Answer (score 0):

eXosip_t is a `typedef struct`. You must use `struct` keyword, when declaring variable. Variable `ctx` wasn't declared previously anywhere.